# How to run routes in Controllers - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have three routes in my application that i want to run in a function in my controller. Now, when the function is called, the routes in the function must as well execute. Below is how i have coded it. The routes executed in the `getData` calls their related functions in the same controller.

PS: This is might not be the right way to achieve this.

But how can i achieve this?

**Controller**

```
public function getData(Request $request)
{
    $message = new Message( array(
            'title' => $request->get('title'),
            'description' => $request->get('description'),
            'branch_id' => Auth::user()->branch_id,
            'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
        ));
        $message->save();

     return redirect('getproducts');
     return redirect('getcustomer');
     return redirect('getshop');
}



 public function getProducts()
    { //do something
    }
public function getCustomer()
    {// do something
    }
public function getShop()
    { // do something
     }
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('getproducts',Controller@getProducts);
Route::get('getCustomer',Controller@getCustomer);
Route::get('getshop',Controller@getShop);
```

Comment: You can't return multiple things. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? Your `getData` function can do `$this->getProducts()` etc., but you'll have to combine their output into a single return value (which can be an array).

Comment: @ceejayoz Now those functions placed in `getData` are basically suppose to send notifications. I just need to run the 3 functions to send the notification when `getData()` is called

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use `$message = new Message( array(` and the rest of the `getData` (except redirects) on all other `get*` methods/actions in your Controller class, then you can move the `$message = new Message( array(` code block in a `private` method like this:

```
private function getDataHelper(Request $request)
{
    $message = new Message([
        'title' => $request->get('title'),
        'description' => $request->get('description'),
        'branch_id' => Auth::user()->branch_id,
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
    ]);

    return $message->save();
}
```

Then you simply redefine the structure of your `public get*` methods:

```
public function getProducts(Request $request)
{
    return $this->getDataHelper($request);
}

public function getCustomer(Request $request)
{
    return $this->getDataHelper($request);
}

public function getShop(Request $request)
{
    return $this->getDataHelper($request);
}
```

Maybe not the most efficient way, but it will do the work. You'd probably want to remove the `return`'s in the `public get*` methods.

---

**EDIT:**

Or if you want to redirect conditionally, based on either `title` or `description` parameters from your request, you can do the following, with preserving most of your code:

```
private function getDataHelper(Request $request)
{
    $message = new Message([
        'title' => $request->get('title'),
        'description' => $request->get('description'),
        'branch_id' => Auth::user()->branch_id,
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id
    ]);

    $title = $request->get('title');
    $description = $request->get('description');

    if($title === 'products' || $description === 'products') {
        return redirect('getproducts');
    }

    if($title === 'customer' || $description === 'customer') {
        return redirect('getcustomer');
    }

    if($title === 'shop' || $description === 'shop') {
        return redirect('getshop');
    }

    // otherwise redirect home
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Note that I guessed the conditions do to the proper redirections.

Comment: Now those functions placed in `getData` are basically suppose to send notifications. I just need to run the 3 functions to send the notification when `getData()` is called

Comment: I still don't understand your work flow of your `getData` method, thus I cannot find which condition would you use to separate the redirects.